# Gulp task to increment a major, minor, or patch level of the version number of the last build

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, gulp.js

**Working codepen:** http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/oxwLzE?editors=1010

The function below takes in user entered text through the cli: `V=patch gulp build`

It then checks for the last version of the build folder, then iterates the appropriate version number.

Hoping to condense all the if/else into more functional code.

lastVersion starts as an empty string `var lastVersion = '';`

The `ver` value that is passed into this function from the user will be 1 of these commands:

- `V=major gulp build`
- `V=minor gulp build`
- `V=patch gulp build`

So `ver` will be `major`, `minor` or `patch`...

---

```
function generateNextVersion(ver) {
    var major, minor, patch;
    var versionArray = lastVersion.split('.');

    major = parseInt(versionArray[0]);
    minor = parseInt(versionArray[1]);
    patch = parseInt(versionArray[2]);

    if (ver === 'major') {
        major = parseInt(versionArray[0]) + 1;
    }
    else if (ver === 'minor') {
        minor = parseInt(versionArray[1]) + 1;
    }
    else if (ver === 'patch') {
        patch = parseInt(versionArray[2]) + 1;
    }

    version = major + '.' + minor + '.' + patch;

    if (ver === '' || ver === undefined) {
        version = '0.0.0';
    }

    gutil.log(gutil.colors.blue.bold('##################################################'));
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.blue.bold('         Building Dashboard version '+version));
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.green.bold('~~           All change is detectable           ~~'));
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.blue.bold('##################################################'));
}
```

Comment: What is `lastVersion`? We are missing something here, it'd be helpful if you post a working demo.

Comment: Added additional info, this is a gulpfile process, just created a codepen here: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/oxwLzE?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I see is that:

```
    major = parseInt(versionArray[0]) + 1;
```

Is a bit redundant. You already say:

```
major = parseInt(versionArray[0]);
```

Just do:

```
major += 1;
```

(This is similar for all the `major`, `minor` and `patch` statements)

You can also use a `switch-case` instead of if statements so instead of:

```
if (ver === 'major') {
    major = parseInt(versionArray[0]) + 1;
}
else if (ver === 'minor') {
    minor = parseInt(versionArray[1]) + 1;
}
else if (ver === 'patch') {
    patch = parseInt(versionArray[2]) + 1;
}
```

You have:

```
switch (ver) {
    case 'major':
        major += 1;
        break;
    case 'minor':
        minor += 1;
        break;
    case 'patch':
        patch += 1;
        break;
}
```